# Proper behavior when overloading casts to have class behave identically to pointers

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I want to have a class behave identically to pointers, *but* also support the comparison operators, like `<` and `>`.

I am running into casting troubles:

```
ptr_t<foo> x = new foo;
(bar*)x;              // cast should be allowed
static_cast<bar*>(x); // cast should fail
```

The above snippet should behave as if `ptr_t<foo>` was `foo*`.

Here is the cast operator:

```
template <typename cast_t>
explicit inline operator cast_t() {
  return (cast_t)(ptr); // causes static_cast to use C-style, which is bad
}
```

If I use C-style in the definition then `static_cast` becomes unsafe. If I use `static_cast` then the C-style becomes less useful. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would you want the `static_cast` to fail? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `ptr<foo>` should have the same behavior as `foo*`. `foo` and `bar` are unrelated classes.

Comment: I don't think you can tell the compiler to exact-match `ptr_t<foo>` to `foo*` for fun, and you'd need to to make that C-style cast do a `reinterpret_cast` for you, without a conversion operator (which would make `static_cast` work).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily emulate `ptr_t<foo>` acting like `foo*` by overloading the arrow and dereference operators, whilst providing a `get` function. This is how all smart pointer operate (by convention), and it's much more natural to work with. Messing around with casts seems needlessly complicated and fragile.

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_t
{
    T* get() const;

    T* operator->() const
    {
        return get();
    }

    T& operator*() const
    {
        return *get();
    }
};
```

---

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() const;
};

void baz(foo*);

ptr_t<foo> x = /* .. */;

x->bar();
(*x).bar();
baz(x.get());
```

Comment: Note that the conversion is not implicit in the example.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'll be damned, I'm used to ignoring that.

Comment: This works, although their behavior isn't the same. I need to be able to use both pointers and ptr_t in templates.

Comment: @Pubby: Your question says nothing of the sort. [Perhaps you should describe your goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: @Gman *"I want to have a class behave identically to pointers"* is my goal. Your answer is helpful, but is not precisely what I need.

Comment: @Pubby: No class will behave identically to pointers, ever. Your question is moot. If you have some specific domain in which specific constraints are applied, you can emulate it, but a class simply isn't a pointer and you need to accept that.

Comment: @Pubby "_"I want to have a class behave identically to pointers" is my goal._" then you need to change your question. What the use case for your class?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution to my own problem, but I realized this may be helpful to future viewers:

```
template<typename t>
using ptr_t = t*;
```

This will cause `ptr_t<foo>` to behave identically to `foo*` (technically it's the same type)

Unfortunately I need to overload `<` and `>` to be different from a regular pointer, and so this does not work in my case.

Comment: Hey! That's my `dumb_ptr`! (for what is worth, this will cause `ptr_t<foo>` to *be* `foo*`. It's an alias not a new type. Other than having different syntax, it's the same) Relevant: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/dumb-ptr

Comment: This doesn't "cause `ptr_t<foo>` to behave identically to `foo*`"; it makes the two actually be the same type. It may sound like I'm being pedantic, but in fact this subtly makes this whole answer completely irrelevant to anything ever.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Good point. I agree this isn't a very useful answer, I might delete it.

Comment: `std::less<T*>` is defines a total order, even if `<` doesn't. Would that solve your problem? Maybe you could explain why you want the comparisons.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes My `<` is using std::less. I thought it would be easier than typing std::less over and over.

Comment: +1, because it is the **only** correct answer to your requirements "_behave identically to pointers_". You have to understand that your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a class behave identically to pointers, but

Your requirements obviously cannot be fulfilled:

**If it behaves like a pointer, it is a pointer.**

So, it is not a class, you cannot define overloads, etc.

Surprisingly, this is a common question if you substitute some other type for "pointers".